# Giving fields values without stating the names of the fields

Tags: java, reflection

My program has a class that has a large number of fields.  I need to be able to create a new instance of this class from two previously existing instances.  It would randomly choose which fields it gets from which of the two previous instances.

Obviously I could just do a bunch of these:

```
if(random.nextBoolean())
    this.value = a.value;
else:
    this.value = b.value;
```

However, I have always been intrigued by some of the methods found in ClassName.class.  I have tried researching this before but, I never had any luck.  So let me show you what I would like to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Specimen.class.getDeclaredFields().length; i++){
if(random.nextBoolean())
    this.fields[i] = a.fields[i];
else
    this.fields[i] = b.fields[i];
```

It is my understanding that this is not possible with reflection, is there another way?

Comment: This is possible with reflection. You will need to change the field to accessible first though (if it is private).

Comment: Yeah thanks Steven.  In another stackoverflow question they were saying it wasn't possible with reflection to pretty much the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Field` holds more then just the value of the field.

To get the value of the field, you need to use one of the `set`/`get` methods.  For example.

```
if(random.nextBoolean())
    this.fields[i].set(a.fields[i].get());
else
    this.fields[i].set(b.fields[i].get());
```

Comment: Thanks!  That is so cool.  I didn't think fields would be use full because they weren't class specific, and couldn't hold/set class specific data.  But that makes sense.  Your awesome.

Comment: Lol, I had already written up 13 of the 28 if/else statements i would of needed.